# XPath select element with an attribute

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a xml file which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
 <alarm-response-list xmlns="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response"   
 error="EndOfResults" throttle="277" total-alarms="288">
 <alarm-responses> 
  <alarm id="53689bf8-6cc8-1003-0060-008010186429">
   <attribute id="0x11f4a" error="NoSuchAttribute" /> 
   <attribute id="0x12b4c">UPS DIAGNOSTIC TEST FAILED</attribute> 
   <attribute id="0x10b5a">IDG860237, SL3-PL4, US, SapNr=70195637,</attribute> 
 </alarm>
 <alarm id="536b8c9a-28b3-1008-0060-008010186429">
  <attribute id="0x11f4a" error="NoSuchAttribute" /> 
  <attribute id="0x12b4c">DEVICE IN MAINTENANCE MODE</attribute> 
  <attribute id="0x10b5a">IDG860237, SL3-PL4, US, SapNr=70195637,</attribute> 
</alarm>
</alarm-responses>
</alarm-response-list>
```

There a lot of these alarms. Now I want save for every alarm tag the attribute with the id = 0x10b5a in a String. But I haven't a great clue. In my way it doesn't do it. I get only showed the expression.

My idea:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(
                new File(
                        "alarms.xml"));

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        System.out.println("*************************");
        String expression = "/alarm-responses/alarm/attribute[@id='0x10b5a'] ";
        System.out.println(expression);
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(
                xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild()
                    .getNodeValue());
        }
```

Comment: Since <alarm-responses> is not the root element, try the following xpath expression: "//alarm-responses/alarm/attribute[@id='0x10b5a'] "

Comment: now i get a null pointer exception

Comment: System.out.println(nodeList.item(i)                .getNodeValue());  Depending on where the null pointer is occurring, this might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different problems here that are interacting to mean that your XPath expression doesn't match anything.  Firstly the `alarm-responses` element isn't the root of the document - you need an extra step on the front of the path to select the `alarm-response-list` element.  But more importantly you have namespace issues.

XPath only works when the XML has been parsed with namespaces enabled, which for some reason is not the default for `DocumentBuilderFactory`.  You need to enable namespaces before you do `newDocumentBuilder`.

Now your XML document has `xmlns="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response"`, which puts all the elements in this namespace, but unprefixed node names in an XPath expression always refer to nodes that are not in a namespace.  In order to match namespaced nodes you need to bind a prefix to the namespace URI and then use prefixed names in the path.

For `javax.xml.xpath` this is done using a `NamespaceContext`, but annoyingly there is no default implementation of this interface available by default in the Java core library.  There is a [SimpleNamespaceContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/util/xml/SimpleNamespaceContext.html) implementation available as part of Spring, or it's fairly simple to write your own.  Using the Spring class:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
        .newInstance();

// enable namespaces
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

// Set up the namespace context
SimpleNamespaceContext ctx = new SimpleNamespaceContext();
ctx.bindNamespaceUri("ca", "http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response");
xPath.setNamespaceContext(ctx);

System.out.println("*************************");

// corrected expression
String expression = "/ca:alarm-response-list/ca:alarm-responses/ca:alarm/ca:attribute[@id='0x10b5a']";

System.out.println(expression);
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(
        xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
}
```

Note also how I'm using `getTextContent()` to get the text under each matched element.  The `getNodeValue()` method always returns `null` for element nodes.

Comment: thank you a lot! one problem is still there. how i can include SimpleNamespaceContext? with which import command? eclipse doesn't sugget one- ah i understand  have I write it myself? I doesn't know how :(

Comment: @LittleProgrammer the SimpleNamespaceContext class I used is part of the Spring framework, you need the `spring-core` JAR (if you're not using anything else from Spring you just need that JAR, not the other ones it depends on).  Or just copy the implementation into your own project, it's pretty simple and released under the Apache licence: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/xml/SimpleNamespaceContext.java